# Streaming FFmpeg over TCP

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm experimenting with streaming video using the following basic method, which works fine:

```
$ ffmpeg -re -i INPUT -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:2000
$ ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:2000
```

However, when replacing udp with tcp (see [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)), ffmpeg says "connection refused".

```
[tcp @ 0x7f9ddb408880] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:2000 failed: Connection refused
tcp://127.0.0.1:2000: Connection refused
```

How do I fix this?

(All articles I find on the "connection refused" topic relate to FFserver, which is discontinued.)

Using macOS + FFmpeg  4.0.3

Comment: You’ll have to have something listening at the address and port you want to send the stream to. UDP is connectionless, TCP requires a connection

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I suspected this. Thanks for pointing this out. I could achieve this by starting the client first, of course. But if not, what are my other options? Can I set up some generic buffering mechanism in nginx that passes the data through to connecting clients on the other side, or do I basically need a streaming server like RTMP?

Answer (score 3):

Did you specify the "listen" option on one side?
i.e. 
 `ffmpeg -re -i INPUT -f mpegts tcp://127.0.0.1:2000\?listen`

Answer (score 2):

> Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:2000 failed: Connection refused

This could also appear when there is a process/program already running at that port (in your case, port 2000) and you try to run another program on it or run the same program once more.

You can use,

```
netstat -tupln
```

to see if any program is running on that port.

If you want to run any program while a program is already running on that port, you can kill the existing program using,

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i:<port_number>)
```

In your case,

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i:2000)
```

After killing the program on the port you can try `ffmpeg` command again.

Comment: This is a good reminder to check in this or similar situations, though this wasn't an issue in this case. (See comment for probable cause.)